# Run NSTimer certain number of times

Tags: ios, nstimer

Is it possible to run an NSTimer like so:

```
NSTimer *f = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate date]
                                      interval:.05
                                        target:self
                                      selector:@selector(checkForCollisions)
                                      userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:f forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[f release];
```

but specify the number of times I want it to run? So, if I wanted it to run for just 2 seconds (assuming the interval of .05), I could specify it to run 40 times? Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YourViewController.h

```
NSTimer *f;
NSInteger counter;
```

YourViewController.m

```
- (void)setup {
    // initialization code
    counter = 0;
    f = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate date]
                                 interval:.05
                                   target:self
                                 selector:@selector(checkForCollisions)
                                 userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runner addTimer:f forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)checkForCollisions {
    // handle check

    counter++;
    if (counter >= 40) {
        [f invalidate];
        [f release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, be aware changes in run loop mode can delay a timer from firing.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int numberOfTimes = 0;
static int inAndOut = 0;
...

int interval = 0.5;
int 2seconds = 120;
numberOfTimes = 2seconds/interval;

- (void) checkForCollisions {
    if (numberOfTimes <= inAndOut) {
        //check collisions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just decrement a counter in the checkForCollisions method.